Temperature Control and Current Monitor not working as per the schematic
Image-1

Image-2

Image-3

Please look into the above images. It is part of the schematic of my design.
I have added the features of temperature monitor(MON_TEMP) and current monitor(MON_CUR)
The supply given to the circuit is VD_IN which is equal to 28V.
Temperature Monitor must work such that once the Temperature sensing IC (LM57-Q1) detects temperature above 70 deg Celsius, then the circuit must turn OFF.
But during testing, i have increased the temperature of the board environment through an external heater and observed that the board is not turning OFF at all. I have gone up to 110 degrees celsius as well but the circuit didn't turn OFF.
Here, i am checking the voltage at the MON_TEMP point. I am observing that the voltage is equal to 1.4V at room temperature and 1.1V at around 80 deg celsius.
What maybe the reason for the circuit to not shutdown even though the temperature senser IC is working fine.
For Current Monitoring, when i am measuring the voltage at the MON_CUR point, I am getting 0V. My end load at the output pins of my circuit board is 15 ohms rheostat. But i can see that the whole circuit along with the 15ohm load connected is consuming 2.2A of current when i am giving 28V supply to the board, through the regulated power supply.
Please tell where does the issue lie in the circuit.
